# What is meant by setting semi-tone on Guitar Tuner?

Tags: guitar, tuner

On a guitar tuner there’s a setting to set semi-tone. Options are Off, b, bb. What do these options mean? While I understand that semi-tone means interval of half-tone (one fret), I need some understanding of how b & bb are related in terms of Tuner setup.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tuners are generally set at A=440Hz. Concert pitch. With so many guitarists tuning down these days, the tuner can be reset so that the whole guitar is one semitone low,(b) as in Eb for top and bottom, or down to D, (bb),where the guitar is one tone lower than standard.

So, your tuner has 3 settings - standard, one semitone flat, or one tone flat.